# Node.js process.nextTick() где и как использовать?

Tags: node.js, event-loop

Не совсем могу понять практическое применение `process.nextTick()`. Как я понял, nextTick() позволяет вернуть ответ пользователю при следующем tick`е в event loop не дожидаясь его обхода до IOCallbacks(могу ошибаться). Верно ли что для понимания nextTick() нужные глубокие, а не поверхностные знания event loop`а?

Comment: Возможно, это поможет разобраться: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt Спасибо, гляну уже позже. Можно вопрос... Насколько хороша официальная документация nodejs? Сам не большой специалист, а опыт работы с непопулярными фреймворками с плохой документацией оставил свой след, увы.

Comment: Официальная английская документация к API достаточно полная и актуальная, она всегда активно пополняется и шлифуется. Раздел со статьями (как по моей ссылке) может в некоторых деталях не поспевать за новыми версиями Node.js, но в основах он верен. Всегда актуальных русских переводов, насколько я знаю, пока нет.

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt ага... русские переводы документаций я решил давно не трогать, больше вреда чем пользы для знаний. На счет раздела со статьями... я всегда (т.к. вообще не спец юзать cerrent версии) ориентируюсь на LTS, верно ли я думаю что статьи для LTS версий 90%+  актуальны (понятное дело, что полученные знания нужно, опробовать и проверить даже после офф. документации?)

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt я только сейчас понял, что не совсем правильно и рано сформулировал вопрос. После изучения статьи я или правлю вопрос или сформулирую и задам его заново. Из за непонимания механизмов и вопрос то толком сформулировать сложно... я просто опасаюсь, могу ли я и если да, то как, навредить себе бездумным или неправильно понятым nextTik(). В любом случае огромное спасибо за направление. Дальнейшее обсуждение будет иметь смысл после прочтения той статьи.

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, весь блок статей написан достаточно давно. Думаю, с тех пор уже не одна LTS сменилась. Так что, скорее всего, для последней LTS они на 100% верны. Можно всегда посмотреть историю правок на Гитхабе (API документация в основном репозитории, статьи в репозитории сайта). Например, последние правки к статье по ссылке довольно незначительны: https://github.com/nodejs/nodejs.org/commits/master/locale/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick.md

Comment: Как вы прочитаете в статье, ваше замешательство может быть вызвано неудачным наименованием методов, оставшихся в наследие от старых версий. Это частая путаница, вы тут не одиноки. Главное понять суть и не привязываться к смыслу названия.

Comment: Кстати, об event loop есть популярная видеолекция: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ Она старенькая, но всё ещё актуальная. Правда, посвящена она браузерной среде исполнения, но достаточно заменять в уме Web API в ролике на Node.js API, чтобы понять схему.